# How to implement roles functionalism in Asp.net Mvc 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I'm trying to pass the roleName to be added in text box an error is thrown by VS that

> "Cannot connect to sql server"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About(string roleName)
{
     System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole(roleName);
     return View();
}
```

Please let me know how to correct this error.

Comment: What connection are you using to connect to database

Comment: I'm using ConnectionString in web.config to connect.

Comment: Kindly give the Detail of the DB structure, and whether you are using COde First or Model First

Comment: Hey @ArijitMukherjee its working fine now. I removed the roleManager codes from web.config   I installed for Roles through packageManager

Comment: Plus I wasn't signed in That's why it wasn't adding the roles. Silly mistake of mine. Thanks for your help.